# highlight points in ggplot2 stat_qq output

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to highlight selected points based on their order statistics in a ggplot stat_qq output:

```
ydata <- data.frame(sample = c(rep("Sample 1", 100),
                               rep("Sample 2", 100),
                               rep("Sample 3", 100),
                               rep("Sample 4", 100)),
                               x=rnorm(400))

ydata <- ydata[order(ydata$sample, ydata$x),]
ydata$order <- 1:100

ggplot(ydata, aes(sample=x)) + stat_qq() + facet_wrap(~sample) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = -2:2, labels = function(x) paste0(x, " \n [",100 * signif(pnorm(-2:2, lower.tail=FALSE),2), "%]")) + theme_bw(base_size = 14, base_family = "sans") + labs(title = "Four Samples of 100 Observations From Normal Distribution", 
       caption = "4 Samples of n = 100 from Normal Distribution \nNumbers indicate order of value",
       y = "Sample Value",
       x = "Standard Deviation\n[%exceeding]") +  
  geom_text(data = ydata[ydata$order %in% c(2,16,50,84,98),], aes(x=qnorm(pnorm(x)), y=x, label = order), nudge_y = 1)
```

Which produced this:

[image]

Obviously my text notation is not highlighting the right points (the 2, 16, 50 84, 98th points). I wish I could also highlight the actual points in red. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply stat="qq" to your geom_point and then use the colors assigned to new variable

```
ydata <- data.frame(sample = c(rep("Sample 1", 100),
                               rep("Sample 2", 100),
                               rep("Sample 3", 100),
                               rep("Sample 4", 100)),
                    x=rnorm(400))

ydata <- ydata[order(ydata$sample, ydata$x),]
ydata$order <- 1:100
ydata$highlight = ifelse(ydata$order %in% c(2,16,50,84,98), "#FF0000", "#000000")
ydata$order_txt = ifelse(ydata$order %in% c(2,16,50,84,98), ydata$order, "")

ggplot(ydata, aes(sample=x)) + 
  geom_point(color=ydata$highlight, stat="qq")  +
  geom_text(label=ydata$order_txt, stat="qq", nudge_y=1) +
  facet_wrap(~sample) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = -2:2, labels = function(x) paste0(x, " \n [",100 * signif(pnorm(-2:2, lower.tail=FALSE),2), "%]")) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 14, base_family = "sans") + 
  labs(
    title = "Four Samples of 100 Observations From Normal Distribution",
    caption = "4 Samples of n = 100 from Normal Distribution \nNumbers indicate order of value",
    y = "Sample Value",x = "Standard Deviation\n[%exceeding]")
```

Comment: When you use `highlight` as a colour aesthetic, does that result in the qq values being calculated separately for the non-highlighted and highlighted points?

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about that. I changed the response to fix this

Comment: I wish I could vote for both your excellent answers - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the qq values outside of ggplot and create a separate column to group the qq values into highlighted and not highlighted. Then you could plot them using `geom_point` with the grouping variable as a colour aesthetic. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate data reproducibly
set.seed(2)
ydata <- data.frame(sample = c(rep("Sample 1", 100),
                               rep("Sample 2", 100),
                               rep("Sample 3", 100),
                               rep("Sample 4", 100)),
                    x=rnorm(400))

ydata <- ydata[order(ydata$sample, ydata$x),]
ydata$order <- 1:100

# Quantile indices to highlight
pts = c(2,16,50,84,98)

# Add qq values and grouping column to data frame and pipe into ggplot
# Use split and map to calculate the qq values separately for each Sample
split(ydata, ydata$sample) %>% 
  map_df(~ .x %>% mutate(xq = qqnorm(x, plot.it=FALSE)$x,
                         group = ifelse(order %in% pts, "A", "B"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xq, x, colour=group)) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(group=="A", order, "")), 
            nudge_y=1, size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~ sample) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14, base_family = "sans") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "black")) +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

As an alternative, a quick hack would be to use `ggplot_build` to highlight specific points in your original plot (note though that something is not quite right with how you placed the labels relative to the highlighted points):

```
pts = rep(c(2,16,50,84,98), 4) + rep(seq(0,300,100), each=5)

# Assuming you've assigned your plot to the object p
pb = ggplot_build(p)

# Change point colors
pb$data[[1]][pts, "colour"] = "red"

# Change label colors
pb$data[[2]][["colour"]] = "red"

# Regenerate plot object
p = ggplot_gtable(pb)
plot(p)
```

[image]